# Django API: Problem with Displaying a Field

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in Django. Right now, I am working with the APIs. I am facing a problem. I can't view one of the fields, called `label`, at http://127.0.0.1:8000/gameapi/. Here is the screenshot:
[image]
Here are my codes of `serializers.py` located inside **gamreview** folder.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Game, Tags


class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tags
        fields = ['label']

class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # label_tag = TagSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'developer', 'platform']
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'developer', 'platform','label_tag']

def create(self, validated_data):
    label_tag_data = validated_data.pop('label_tag')
    game = Game.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for tags_data in label_tag_data:
        Tags.objects.create(game=game, **tags_data)
    return Game.objects.create(**validated_data)

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
    instance.developer = validated_data.get('developer', instance.developer)
    instance.platform = validated_data.get('platform', instance.platform)
    instance.tag = TagSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Here are my codes of `models.py` under **gamreview** folder:

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

# Create your models here.

class Tags(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.label


class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    developer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='null')
    label_tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, default='null')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class Review(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    review = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, default='null')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.game
```

Here are my codes of `views.py` under **gamreview** folder:

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Game
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import GameSerializer


# Create your views here.


class GameListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'gamereview/gamelist.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_games'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Game.objects.all()


class ReviewView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Game
    template_name = 'gamereview/review.html'

# class GameApiView(generics.ListAPIView):
class GameApiView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Game.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GameSerializer

class GameDetailApiView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Game.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GameSerializer
```

Here are my codes of `urls.py` under **gamreview** folder:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'gamereview'

urlpatterns = [
    path('gamereview/', views.GameListView.as_view(), name='gamelist'),
    path('gamereview/<slug:slug>/', views.ReviewView.as_view(), name='review'),
    path('gameapi/', views.GameApiView.as_view(), name='gamelistapi'),
    path('gameapi/<int:pk>/', views.GameDetailApiView.as_view()),


]
```

I don't get any error while running the server. However, the `label` field is not showing up.
How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `fields` twice in `GameSerializer`- `Meta` class. Delete the first one.

```
class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # label_tag = TagSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'developer', 'platform'] --> delete this
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'developer', 'platform','label_tag']
```

Comment: It fixes that issue. However, I am facing another issue. Instead of seeing `"label_tag": "racing"`, I am seeing `"label_tag": [1]`. That means, I am not getting the string value.

Comment: Should I post a new question about the issue?

Comment: I have posted a new question about the specific issue. Would you please take a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59115673/django-rest-framework-api-unable-to-get-string-value-of-a-field

Answer (score 0):

Django rest framework relies on `related_name` attribute to the resolve foreign key fields. 
I think just changing your Game model so would do it

```
  label_tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tags, related_name="label")
```